# Angular Material - show mat-error on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to do validation using the `<mat-form-field>` and `<mat-error>`. This works fine when user tabs out of the input without filling. But how do I force this error to show when I click a button? I am not using submit. Also, using template-driven forms.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Due Date" name="dueDate" [(ngModel)]="dueDate" [formControl]="dueDateValidator" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="dueDateValidator.invalid">Due Date is required for Tasks</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

`dueDateValidator: FormControl =  new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);`

Comment: Look into [custom error matchers](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#custom-error-matcher)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### See how to use a form with a custom [ErrorStateMatcher](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#custom-error-matcher)

> If you wish to override this behavior (e.g. to show the error as soon
>   as the invalid control is dirty or when a parent form group is
>   invalid), you can use the errorStateMatcher property of the matInput.
>   The property takes an instance of an ErrorStateMatcher object. An
>   ErrorStateMatcher must implement a single method isErrorState which
>   takes the FormControl for this matInput as well as the parent form and
>   returns a boolean indicating whether errors should be shown. (true
>   indicating that they should be shown, and false indicating that they
>   should not.)

I would make a separate file such as default.error-matcher.ts

```js
/** Error when invalid control is dirty or touched*/
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched));
  }
}
```

Then in the TS file add:

```
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

Then change the input to use matcher:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Due Date" name="dueDate" [(ngModel)]="dueDate" [formControl]="dueDateValidator" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="dueDateValidator.invalid">Due Date is required for Tasks</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Advanced: if you're creating your own custom form controls the `[errorStateMatcher]` is part of the `CanUpdateErrorState` interface

Answer (score 33):

Since you want to show mat error on button's click, please try the below:
For Angular6 version:

1. Import the required classes

```
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
```

2. Declare form control in your component.ts file:

```
nameControl = new FormControl('');
```

3. Add the control in html:

```html
<mat-form-field  style="width: 100%" floatPlaceholder="never">
    <input matInput placeholder="your placeholder text" [formControl]="nameControl" required/>
    <mat-error *ngIf="nameControl.errors?.required">name is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

4. Add this to your button click event handler:

```
this.nameControl.markAsTouched();
```

It's important to check how you are using the form control, ".markAsTouched()" on point 4 will show the mat error for the corresponding form control.

Comment: @Simran What is the function of '?' in errors?.required

Comment: @DipendraGurung it checks whether the error arisen for the control is for "required", if the control error is for required validation then error message should appear stating "name is required" similarly error can be checked for the pattern.

Comment: I used ```this.nameControl.setErrors({ invalid: true });``` and ```<mat-error *ngIf="nameControl.hasError('invalid')">Some error message!</mat-error>```

Answer (score 23):

Angular 8 has a new forms method: `markAllAsTouched();`

This will mark a control/form and ALL DESCENDANTS as touched!!!

So:

```
this.form.markAllAsTouched();
```

Is the solution.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me. :) On button's click:

```
this.nameControl.markAsTouched();
```

Answer (score 7):

I am providing 3 different solutions for different scenarios, use the one which suits you.

- If you are using a form, then do

  ```
  this.form.markAllAsTouched();
  ```
- If you need a particular field to be affected inside form, then filter that nameControl and do

  ```
  nameControl.markAsTouched();
  ```
- If you are **not using forms**, then specify a `ref` for the `input` element and initialize variable in ts file & do as follows,

  ```
  @ViewChild('myInputRef') myInputRef; // Initialize the ref of input element
  .
  .
  this.myInputRef.control.markAsTouched()
  ```

Comment: If not using forms, `this.myInputRef.control` returns undefined.

Comment: Make sure you do specify 'ngModel' for #myInputRef. Like this`<input #myInputRef="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="value" />`

Answer (score 4):

Either you can do as "Kyle Pfromer" suggested or as you are using form group, you can mark element as touched on submit with

```
onSubmit(){ this.formName.get('formControlName').markAsTouched(); }
```

Comment: This one is PERFECT!

Answer (score 3):

Based on Kyle Pfromer's post, I found my solution (to the same problem):

In the TS file I added the StateMatcher after I found an invalid form, eg.

```
if (this.myFormGroup.invalid) {
  this.matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
  return;
}
```

In the MyErrorStateMatcher class I changed as following:

```
    return !!(control && control.invalid);
```

I find it confusing that Angular Material is not detecting the error anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**GLOBALLY: Show mat-error while typing or touched**:
Unlike the provided solution, this method will take care of all mat-errors in the app without applying the matcher to each input.

1- Create **touched-error-state.matcher.ts** file:

```
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

export class TouchedErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
    isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
        return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched));
    }
}
```

2- In **app.module** import:

```
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';
import { TouchedErrorStateMatcher } from './your-folder-path/touched-error-state.matcher';
```

3- Now provide it into the providers:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UserService,
    { provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: TouchedErrorStateMatcher }
  ],
})
```

4- Re-Serve the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can also easily call the `AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity()` function on button click. This will run the validation process on the corresponding ForControl again and show errors, if there are some (based on your Validators).

So, in your example:

```
    checkForErrorsOnButtonClick(): void {
      dueDateValidator.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is call markUserNameTouched() method as below on button click on template. We use markAsTouched() on formControl.

```
public staffLoginForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(){
this.staffLoginForm = new FormGroup({
username: new FormControl(null),
password: new FormControl(null)});

markUserNameTouched():void{
  this.staffLoginForm.get('username').markAsTouched();
}
```