# FormArray on save button click does not display mat error

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a save button outside form. on save button click i want to display `mat error`. But it does not get displayed. I Tried using `this.form.markAsDirty()` & `this.form.markASTouched()` but nothing works.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <div formArrayName="products" *ngFor="let product of form.get('products').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" formControlName="productCode">
      <mat-error>
          Blank Error
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" formControlName="productName">
      <mat-error>
          Blank Error
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
   </div>
  </div>
<form>
<div>
   <button type="button" (click)="SaveProducts()">Save</button>
</div>

angular code:

addProduct() {
  this.form.get('products').push(this.getProductGroup())
}

SaveProducts() {
  this.form.markAsDirty();
  this.form.markAsTouched();
  if(this.form.valid) {
     //save products
  }
}
```

Comment: `<mat-error *ngIf="form.controls.productCode.errors?.required">
                        ProductCode is <strong>required</strong>
</mat-error>` you want show something like that? or You can create custom validator for dirty and touched

Comment: no, i am not looking for that if else

Comment: I found the fix. I have to loop through entire formarray and access each FormControl and mark it as touched. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you look at this link maybe  its can be help you because some posible condition are there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745171/angular-material-show-mat-error-on-button-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marking the whole `FormGroup` as `touched` is not going to make it's children as touched. That's something that you'll have to do explicitly as Angular is not going to do that implicitly. Read [**this thread**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11774) for more info on the rationale behind that.

That being said, you can explicitly call `markAsTouched` on each `FormControl` in each `FormGroup` in the `'products'` `FormArray`.

Here's how:

```
(<FormArray>this.form.get('products')).controls.forEach((group: FormGroup) => {
  (<any>Object).values(group.controls).forEach((control: FormControl) => { 
      control.markAsTouched();
  }) 
});
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mark-form-array-as-touched?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

---

PS: I've made some more modifications to the `mat-error`s so that they show up only when the `FormField`s are `touched` and are invalid. Also, an ideal user experience would be to `disable` the Save button in the first place. And show the user an error when they touch the fields. Also, marking the field labels as required(`*`) can be considered as a good UX.